# How to make Android Andengine game backward compatible with lower end devices (lower resolution)

Tags: android, andengine

I am developing game using Android Andengine.
I am using camera width 720 and camera height 480 but for lowend device like 360 x 480 all Images that I am using are compressed.
code is

```
public Engine onLoadEngine() {
    mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    return new Engine(new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, 
            new FillResolutionPolicy(), mCamera).setNeedsSound(true));
}
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: Please specify the problem more clearly. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

In onCreateEngineOptions() you should specify RatioResolutionPolicy. That will scale your activity to required sizes. You can get the current screen size in method like:

```
private DisplayMetrics getScreenResolutionRatio() {
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    return dm;
}
```

And then specify your RatioResolutionPolicy:

```
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    RatioResolutionPolicy policy = new RatioResolutionPolicy(getScreenResolutionRatio().width, getScreenResolutionRatio().height);
    return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_SENSOR, policy, this.mCamera);
}
```

Comment: I see you have some trouble with code formatting. The trick is to do it "in reverse", first paste the code as text to the question, make sure the indentation is OK and then highlight the whole code and click the Code Sample button.

Comment: yaaa i already added that. but im getting problem for low resolution screen size devices    public Engine onLoadEngine() {
  this.mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
  return new Engine(new EngineOptions(true, 
   ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, 
   new FillResolutionPolicy(), this.mCamera).setNeedsSound(true));
 }

Comment: The problem is that new FillResolutionPolicy() still trying to rescale your scene to the size of your device. RatioResolutionPolicy will give you an opportunity not to use all your screen, but the screen with your parameters

Comment: i want general build for all screen resolution.

Comment: That's why use method getScreenResolutionRatio(), I've described, and get screen metrics. Then set your math logic for calculating required resolution using metrics. And then no matter what screen sizes, you'll have the scene with required aspect ratio.

Comment: I tried with RationResolutionPolicy...still having same issue..   public Engine onLoadEngine() {
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
      requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
      getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

   this.mCamera = new  Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
  System.out.println("The width"+dm.widthPixels);
  return new Engine(new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, new  RatioResolutionPolicy(dm.widthPixels,dm.heightPixels), this.mCamera).setNeedsSound(true));
 }